# what is the use of keys and const

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

in every time I write a code in vscode editor.
every time I get an error the use `key` in widgets and also giving me an alert that prefer to use `const` constructor but what is the real use of it

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your code and screen shots of what your issue is people may understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those widgets which not need to rebuild every time the build() is called, are defined with const keyword. This improves performance of the app, and is best practice to use const keyword with widgets which need no update.
Talking about keys, keys are identifiers for widgets and help Flutter to distinguish between different widgets so that their respective state remain with them, instead of getting assigned to another similar widget.

Answer (score 1):

Components such as appbars orcomponents which need not be updated when the state rebuilds are to be marked with const cosntructors. This practice is not mandatory, but it helps to improve the overall speed and performance of the app. Keys help dart  to uniquely identify widgets and help to get datas out of forms. More about keys [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html)
and [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/keys-in-flutter-104fc01db48f)

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword is used when the value of the `variable` is known at `compile-time` and never changes. In other words, the compiler knows in advance what value is to be stored in that variable.